# Check port number in Linux Kernel Module using Netfilter

Tags: c, linux, kernel, kernel-module, netfilter

Referring to the Netfilter hook code at this [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking)

The port to be checked against is declared as:

```
/* Port we want to drop packets on */
static const uint16_t port = 25;
```

The comparison is made as:

```
return (tcph->dest == port) ? NF_DROP : NF_ACCEPT;
```

In case variable port was of type int32, how can we convert it to uint16_t so that it can be checked against tcph->dest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP ports are only 16 bit wide, so if your `port`-variable contains anything outside the range  0..65535, something is wrong anyway. Also, you should use `ntohs` to account for endianess differences.

So I suggest something like:

```
BUG_ON(port < 0 || port > 65535);
return (ntohs(tcph->dest) == (u16)port) ? NF_DROP : NF_ACCEPT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to have port `int32`? port must be uint16_t. Value greater than 16 `bit` is wrong.